# C++ auto collapsing rules

Tags: c++, auto

Does the standard tell how this code will run?

Note: it is not possible to know in compile-time what value condition is evaluated to below.

Will the generated code have two paths? One where v is collapsed to an rvalue when condition is true, and another where v will be a lvalue when condition is false.

Or will it be that the worst case is assumed and v collapses to an lvalue for both cases?

Or is it simply implementation-defined?

```
struct SomeClass { std::vector<std::string> vec_member_; };

void f(const SomeClass& d, bool condition) {
  auto&& v = (condition) ? 
                std::vector<std::string>{ "fallback case" }
              : d.vec_member_;
  for(auto&& e : v) {
    ... // operate on e (Read only)
  }
}
```

Sorry for formatting. I use an android to edit and can't get the code section fixed after edit.

Comment: What is the type of `SomeClass::vec_member_`?

Answer (score 4):

Expressions in C++ have types.  This includes `?:` expressions.

Your `?:` expression is of type `std::vector<std::string>const`.  The `const` comes from the fact you are accessing `d.member` and the rvalueness comes from the fact one branch of the `?` has a prvalue in it.

Full compiling code that demonstrates this:

```
struct SomeClass {
  std::vector<std::string> vec_member_;
};
void f(bool condition, const SomeClass& d) {
  static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
      decltype((condition) ? std::vector<std::string>{ "fallback case" } : d.vec_member_),
      std::vector<std::string>const
    >
  );
  auto&& v = (condition) ? std::vector<std::string>{ "fallback case" } : d.vec_member_;
  for(auto&& e : v) {
    (void)e;
  }
}
```

`auto&&v` becomes `std::vector<std::string> const&&`.  For the member variable, it binds to a copy.  For the rvalue, it is elided into the temporary materialized to be bound to the rvalue reference `v`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f16bba8d4071b998).

Comment: Can you explain why the prvalue result of the conditional expression is const-qualified? My reading of the standard is that the const lvalue operand should just get converted to the type of the prvalue operand (which is non-const) so the result should not be const-qualified. But obviously I have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Brian I tried, but it blew my stack space.  8.5.16 of course. I think the temporary materialized ends up being a glvalue, and same type ignores r/lvalue and const, so /5 applies (and /3/4 does not), which leads me to the same conclusion as you.  I'd have to language lawyer it.  I worked out the resulting type above through trial and error on is_same_v, and was modestly surprised when I needed to add a `const`.  I have too many balls in the air when trying to read that part of the standard, so my reasoning isn't reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `std::vector<std::string> SomeClass::vec_member_;`
Type of:

```
(condition) ? std::vector<std::string>{ "fallback case" } : d.vec_member_;
```

Would be `const std::vector<std::string>`, so you create a copy in false case,
and work with a temporary in both case.

Answer (score 2):

Every C++ expression belongs to exactly one value category.

```
(condition) ? 
  std::vector<std::string>{ "fallback case" } : 
  d.vec_member_
```

is no exception.

A conditional expression is an lvalue iff the second and the third operand are both lvalues. Otherwise it is a prvalue.

In this case the second operand is not an lvalue, so the entire conditional is a prvalue. It will bind to a rvalue reference, so `auto&&` collapses to that.